# Publish port on docker swarm only to one of the connected networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using a swarm over several nodes to host some web services. The manager node runs traefik as a proxy and ssl endpoint.

Here's a simplified compose file for one of the swarm stacks:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  test1:
    networks:
      - internal
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

  otherservice:
    image: dummy/other
    ports:
      - 9000
    networks:
      - internal
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  loadbalancer:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 9999:8080
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - internal
      - gateway

networks:
  internal:
    external: true
  gateway:
    external: true
```

So basically services are using the network 'internal' which is of type overlay. gateway is a bridge network that's only running on the manager.

Problem is with the above config the ports published on traefik service are published on both networks. Is there any chance to only publish those ports to one of the used networks, in this case gateway?

I want to avoid binding these ports on the other swarm nodes as I need them for other stuff there.

Thanks!

EDIT: to add some information to the problem. Here's what the listening ports on one of my worker nodes look like

```
dockerd    2342            root   44u  IPv6 1439543      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
dockerd    2342            root   50u  IPv6 1439561      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
dockerd    2342            root   52u  IPv6 1439579      0t0  TCP *:9999 (LISTEN)
```

those are not running any container publishing the port - so my suspicion was the ports are published due to the overlay network on the loadbalancer service even though the service isn't running on the worker nodes. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question, a port is bound to an interface on the host, not to a docker network. What error are you encountering?

Comment: @BMitch well I'm encountering that the port is bound to the interfaces of all nodes in the swarm that are attached to the same overlay network. I added more details regarding that to the post.

Comment: Do you want the port to only be bound to a single interface on each node, all interfaces on a single node, or one interface on one node?